# Css minification not working (gulp + cssnano)

Tags: sass, gulp, cssnano

I have a very basic gulpfile set up like this:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var notify = require('gulp-notify');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var useref = require('gulp-useref');
var cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var gulpIf = require('gulp-if');

/*----------  Config settings  ----------*/

var config = {
    devPath: './app/',
    publicPath: './dist/',
    sassDir: 'sass/',
    jsDir: 'js/',
    cssDir: 'css/',
    fontDir: 'fonts/',
    moduleDir: './node_modules',
}

/*----------  Define tasks  ----------*/

gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
    var htmlDir = config.publicPath;

    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: htmlDir
        },
    })
})

gulp.task('sassTask', function () {
    var sassFiles = config.devPath + config.sassDir + '/*.scss';
    var destDir = config.publicPath + config.cssDir;

    return gulp.src(sassFiles)
        .pipe(sass()
            .on("error", notify.onError(function (error) {
                return "Error: " + error.message;
            })))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destDir));
});

gulp.task('useref', function(){
    var htmlFiles = config.devPath + '*.html';
    var destDir = config.publicPath;

    return gulp.src(htmlFiles)
        .pipe(useref())
        // Minifies only if it's a JavaScript file
        .pipe(gulpIf('*.js', uglify()))
        // Minifies only if it's a CSS file
        .pipe(gulpIf('*.css', cssnano()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destDir))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
        }));
});

gulp.task('js', function() {
    var jsFiles = config.devPath + config.jsDir + '**/*.js';    // All files
    var destDir = config.publicPath + config.jsDir;

    return gulp.src(jsFiles)
                .pipe(gulp.dest(destDir));
});

gulp.task('fonts', function() {
    var fontFiles = config.devPath + config.fontDir + '**/*';   // All files
    var destDir = config.publicPath + config.fontDir;

    return gulp.src(fontFiles)
                .pipe(gulp.dest(destDir));
});

/*----------  Define watch  ----------*/

gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync', 'sassTask', 'js', 'useref', 'fonts'], function () {
    var sassFiles = config.devPath + config.sassDir + '**/*.scss';
    var jsFiles = config.devPath + config.jsDir + '**/*.js';
    var htmlFiles = config.devPath + '*.html';
    var fontFiles = config.devPath + config.fontDir + '**/*';

    gulp.watch(sassFiles, ['sassTask', 'useref']);
    gulp.watch(jsFiles, ['js', 'useref']);
    gulp.watch(htmlFiles, ['useref']);
    gulp.watch(fontFiles, ['fonts']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['browserSync', 'sassTask', 'useref', 'fonts']);
```

Everything is working fine when running 'gulp watch' (browser sync, sass, etc.) but the css minification isn't. The outputfile 'style.css' in the dist/css folder isn't minified. What am I doing wrong? Am I missing a module? Thanks in advance for your help.

My file structure:

```
├───app
│   ├───fonts
│   ├───js
│   └───sass
├───dist
│   ├───css
│   │   └───vendor
│   ├───fonts
│   ├───img
│   │   ├───common
│   │   └───layout
│   └───js
│       └───vendor
```

Comment: Does the js files get uglified? It shouldn’t work either.

Comment: Indeed. The js uglifier doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

You should change this sub-task as follows:

```
gulp.task('useref', function(){
    var files = [
        config.devPath + '*.html', 
        config.publicPath + config.jsDir + '*.js',
        config.publicPath + config.cssDir + '*.css'
    ];
    var destDir = config.publicPath;

    return gulp.src(files)
        // Run useref only if it’s an HTML file
        .pipe(gulpIf('*.html', useref()))
        // Minifies only if it's a JavaScript file
        .pipe(gulpIf('*.js', uglify()))
        // Minifies only if it's a CSS file
        .pipe(gulpIf('*.css', cssnano()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destDir))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
        }));
});
```

The first change is in the `htmlFiles` (i changes it to `files` for convenience). You need to change the file pattern to match al desired files: `*.html`, `*.js` and `*.css` in the different folders used as sources, because you want to modify the generated files. Using [node glob patterns](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob/blob/master/README.md) you can easily match the files by file extension passing an array of file patterns, to match different files in different folders..

Then just add a `gulpIf` condition for the `html` files tasks to filter the desired file type (you already have the filter function for the other file types).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried to change my useref sub-task with yours but still no effect.

Comment: @onerkript really? Does the html files get passed to the useref? Can you post you file structure? Probably the pattern should change to match subdirectories `**/{*.html,*.js,*.css}`.

Comment: @onerkript can you post the file structure?

Comment: Ok, I edited my original post with my file structure.

Comment: @onerkript i modified the file pattern. It should work now. Otherwise we can split the pattern in an array.

Comment: Thanks again but now it throws an error:
[14:28:11] 'useref' errored after 110 μs
[14:28:11] ReferenceError: jsDir is not defined

Comment: @onerkript sorry, my mistake, those var are inside the `config` object. Check it now.

Comment: Ok, your code now works but still no minification. The weird thing is that it seems sassTask is finished after useref, see:
[Browsersync] Reloading Browsers... (buffered 2 events)
[14:38:13] Starting 'sassTask'...
[14:38:13] Starting 'useref'...
[Browsersync] 2 files changed (index.html, main.js)
[14:38:13] Finished 'useref' after 16 ms
[14:38:13] Finished 'sassTask' after 23 ms

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173563/discussion-between-muecas-and-onerkript).

Comment: it's working! i changed devPath from your code to publicPath and voila! thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm going crazy. Now minification/uglyfication work but the html isn't working since it's looking in the publicpath. :/